# How to use multiprocess.Pool with .apply function?

Tags: python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I have a function that processes a string and I am applying it on a dataframe column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
def test_upper(d):
    return d.upper()

def mainfunc():
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

    print(df.head())

    lambdafunc = lambda x: test_upper(x)

    df['upper_cols'] = df['cols'].apply(lambdafunc)

    print(df.head())

mainfunc()
```

Now, I want to do the same but with multiprocessing.Pool. I have searched how to do this here in stackoverflow and this is what I came up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def test_upper(d):
    return d.upper()

def mainfunc():
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

    print(df.head())

    lambdafunc = lambda x: test_upper(x)

    list_results = pd.Series()
    def log_result(result):
        list_results.append(result)
        
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.apply_async(lambdafunc, (df['cols'], ), callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(list_results)

mainfunc()
```

The results are blank Series/list as I've tried both. What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out

```
def test_upper(d):
    output = d.apply(lambda x: x:upper())
    return output

def mainfunc():
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

    print(df.head())
        
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.apply_async(test_upper, (df['cols'], ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(result.get())

mainfunc()
```